# It's a question about complements

Tags: grammar, complements

It is important that he ________  what he is learning is worthwhile.

a-believe / b-believes     /c-to believe /d-believing

Why is the answer of this question is a and not b?

Comment: Because he *doesn't* believe it. It is a condition that has yet to happen.

Comment: But if it *has* happened, "believes" is possible too.

Comment: This has nothing to do with complements. Btw, is this a homework question?